# Python matplotlib split time series in multiple plots of fixed interval

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a timestamp index, resulting in a time series 6 hours long from the first to the last timestamp, and 4 variables to plot against. I'd like to split the whole timeseries into fixed intervals of 3 minutes, and create one plot for each interval. There should be 120 plots at the end, each of a duration of 3 minutes and starting from the end of the previous one (e.g. first plot starts x index at 2022-05-16 22:34:27, and ends 2022-05-16 22:37:27. Second plot starts x index at 2022-05-16 22:37:27 and ends 2022-05-16 22:40:27, and that until the last value of of df['Time']. In each of the plots I want to have the Y axis with the corresponding 'Flow', 'HeartTare', 'Pressure', ' O2' values).

The source data (first, second and last rows of a 4700 row table):

| Time | Flow | HeartRate | Pressure | O2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-16 22:34:27 | 2 | 89 | 100 | 90 |
| 2022-05-16 22:34:27 | 3 | 90 | 102 | 95 |
| 2022-05-17 04:37:45 | 1 | 91 | 103 | 98 |

I tried creating a time range of 3 minutes and iterating the plot across each range but the graphs end up empty.

```
import datetime as dt
start = df['Time'].iloc[0]
endt = df['Time'].iloc[len(df['Time']) - 1]
resdate = pd.date_range(start, endt, freq="3min")
for st in resdate:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(5,1)
ax[0].plot(df['Time'], df['Flow'])
ax[1].plot(df['Time'], df['Pressure'])
ax[2].plot(df['Time'], df['O2'])
ax[3].plot(df['Time'], df['HeartRate'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMCrB.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Even if you are not sure of exact implementation, please **try** whatever you can, share the code with us and with the output that is generated with your code, you can clarify in a much better way what the expected output should be. :)

Comment: @medium-dimensional done. Thanks for the tips. I hope it's clear enough now.

Comment: Is the column `Time` sorted? Because the last row in the data frame should have a value similar to *2022-05-18 14:37:00* if the data is collected over 40 hours, and the current data looks like to be collected over 6 hours.

Comment: Sorry, there was an error there. Indeed it's 6 hours long. I just corrected the description. I'm new to posting here...

Comment: No worries! Can you clarify by what you mean by 80 plots? Also, since you have 4 variables, do you wish to plot them on a single y-axis (something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_three.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-three-py))?

Comment: @medium-dimensional There should be 120 plots (6 hours divided in 3 min plots). I'd like to have each variable plotted in individual plots (1 Time Vs Flow, 2 Time Vs pressure, 3 Time Vs. HeartRate, 4 Time Vs. O2).